# Combine Fragment with FragmentActivitiy

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm new to the usage of `Fragments` in android.
Basically I've created a slide menu using Navigation Drawer. So as I understand it all the menu pages are `Fragment`. If I click on home I go to the HomeFragment extending `Fragment` class that has attached its fragment layout. Now I want to implement a tab layout for the home page. but to use tab layout i need to work with Fragments that extend `FragmentActivity`. How do I combine know these 2 things because they are not compatible!

Do I need to create an `Activity` that manages the home fragment? If yes how is this done?

Basically I'm trying to put together 2 sample codes.

1. [Slide menu with navigation draw](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)
2. [Tab layout with slideview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

So I have a class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public Button btnLogout;

    // Session Manager Class
    public SessionManager session;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and another class

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

I basically need to merge them. How?

Comment: post some code, your question is a bit confusing on how you have it set up

Comment: where is your `TabsPagerAdapter` and those 2 links you posted are the same thing. I feel like you really didnt even look at the links because it tells you exactly what to do

Comment: sorry just modified the links! the links tell me 2 different things that seperatly work. but how do i get them to work toghether. thats my problem.

Comment: just replace the `FrameLayout` in the drawer tutorial with a viewpager then put everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `FrameLayout` in the drawer tutorial with a viewpager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

then combine all of the code together in your activity

it will look like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: im sorry, but i still dont get how to merege the 2 classes. the have 2 different onCreate() methods with different parameters, etc. how can i make 1 class out of them?

Comment: you dont merge the 2 classes, a fragment should not be merged to an activity. you should read how to use fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

In the first link you provided, the authour uses a `FrameLayout` to be the main content of his fragments (when calling `add`, `replace`, ...).

In the second one, he creates an activity and enables the action bar by specifiying `actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

If you want to merge the `Drawer` and the `ViewPager`, it depends on what you want to do, you have to possibilities:

1. If you app's main content is a pager with tabs, so you just have to replace the FrameLayout with a `ViewPager` as suggested by Tyczj in his comment.
2. If you want the pager with tabs to be in a fragment, so change the `HomeActivity` to be a `HomeMainFragment` that will handle the `ViewPager` initialisation, and in your `MainActivity` (you have to create it) that will call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)`, call the fragment manager and use a `replace()` method like this:

   ```
   fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FRAME_LAYOUT_ID)
   ```

Let's add a little code for the 2nd method.

**MainActivity** : `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

// ...
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
// ...

}
```

**HomeMainFragment**

```
public class HomeMainFragment extends Fragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.PAGER_LAYOUT, container, false); // PAGER_LAYOUT is the layout that contains your view pager

    return rootView;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the page with tabs will also have a listView of items like text and imeges. which do you recomend? 1. or 2.?

Comment: 1) if you will always have those tabs and the listview (drawer). Read @tyczj's answer for that. If you will want to replace the whole viewpager with another fragment  (without tabs), so i recommend the 2).

Comment: may be ! your activity layout that contains the listview for drawer and the framelayout for main content

Comment: im getting 2 method undefinederrors for setContentView() and findViewById()

Comment: @Pheonix7 you are right, sorry i just copied from your code and edited it. BTW you have to read about fragments, it seems that it's not really clear for you: [check this link](http://www.google.sn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandroidhive.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F05%2Ffragment-activity-in-android-coding.html&ei=KDeiUpzDCfTH7AaK8YBQ&usg=AFQjCNHY1j5ZZ0Idgnhqzn2pjcy46qt8RA)

Comment: @mansoulx : can you give me any demo of this ?? I need demo of second style you teach...

Comment: @mansoulx : can you give me any demo of this ?? I need demo of second style you teach... I do not understand how to use this code FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit(); where fragment means ??

Comment: this link specify my question exactly ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512330/integrating-fragmentactivity-in-fragment